github rest api variables
I'm trying to access the github deloyment vriables using the github rest api.
but I'm unable to get the variables value inside the worlflow. It throws an error
{
  "message": "Resource not accessible by integration",
  "documentation_url": "https://docs.github.com/rest/actions/variables#get-an-environment-variable",
  "status": "403"
}

But when I'm trying to hit the same curl cmd in my local terminal with my personal access token, it works, It gives the expected result.
this is the main yaml file from where I'm calling the health.yml
name: CD

on:
  
  push:
    branches: [ "main" ]
 

  
  workflow_dispatch:


jobs:
  
  deploy:
     uses: ./.github/workflows/deploy.yml
  health-check:
    uses: ./.github/workflows/health.yml
    with: 
      DEPLOYMENT_TYPE: 'dev'
    secrets: inherit

  health-check-prod:
    uses: ./.github/workflows/health.yml
    with: 
      DEPLOYMENT_TYPE: 'prod'
    secrets: inherit

This is the health.yml file
name: health

on:
  workflow_call:
    inputs:
      DEPLOYMENT_TYPE:
        required: true
        type: string
jobs:
  health:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Test variables
        run: |
            curl -L \
            -H "Accept: application/vnd.github+json" \
            -H "Authorization: Bearer ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}" \
            -H "X-GitHub-Api-Version: 2022-11-28" \
            https://api.github.com/repos/${{github.repository}}/environments/${{inputs.DEPLOYMENT_TYPE}}/variables/URL
  

Note: URL in the rest api endpoint is the variable name which  I saved in deployment environment variables.

I tried with my PAT inside the workflow and it works but not with GITHUB_TOKEN

The fact that it works when you use a different access token and that it's returning a 403 code, I assume secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN is set incorrectly, or doesn't have the required permissions. Try issuing the command again but instead of using your personal token use the value of secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN. If it doesn't work with a 403 again, then the token doesn't have the required permissions. If it works, maybe the workflow is not retrieving the proper value of secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN.
EDIT 1:
Given it worked with your PAT in the workflow, it's again pointing to secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN having the wrong permissions.
EDIT 2:
These links might help:
https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/automatic-token-authentication
https://docs.github.com/en/rest/authentication/permissions-required-for-github-apps?apiVersion=2022-11-28

I tried with different rest api endpoints inside the health.yml all works. If it is a permission issue or incorrect secret. Then it should not work for all other end points.

Try this:
jobs:
  health:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    environment: ${{ inputs.DEPLOYMENT_TYPE }}
    steps:
      - name: Test variables
        run: echo ${{ vars.URL }}


Yes, earlier I was doing the same, but the problem is it is a deployment environment and it will require approval and this health check will count as deployment.

GitHub seems to reseve environment’s vars to jobs that declare dependency on an environment. GITHUB_TOKEN is not allowed to access them.
You do not need to have deployment protection rules for an environment and you can just use environments as a source of configuration for shared workflows.
